# How do you select elements in HTML with no ID or Class

Tags: javascript, html

I need to select an anchor element within an HTML document. The only issue is that I cannot find a single ID or Class within the document.

Whenever I run

```
document.querySelector('a')
```

Or

```
document.querySelectorAll('a')
```

I get the error:

> Object doesn't support property or method

Any thoughts?

Comment: You're using a browser that doesn't support `querySelector`

Comment: Show us your HTML and the Javascript that you have tried.

Comment: getElementsByTagName

Comment: What is the browser?

Comment: Can you please give us the rest of your code.

Comment: you should use jquery

Comment: I'm using IE11
HTML is too extensive, but I can't no see an ID or CLASS on any div or form, though within the IE console it shows, html>frameset>frame>html>body>form>table>tbody>tr>td>font>a... perhaps I should try a higher element than the ancor

Comment: given that, you're question is very unclear. Where is this code running? the frameset? the frame? what error are you getting exactly, and on what line of code? none of this makes sense.

Comment: I presume within the frameset... as everything falls under that, save for the <head>.

Comment: Ok, my selection was all jacked up as I've never worked with frames or framesets before.  So, below is how it worked out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, again, as I've never worked with iframes or framesets before, this was somewhat tricky, but I got it to work.

```
document.parentWindow.frames("FrameA").document.all.tags("a")[18].click()
```

Perhaps a bit convoluted, but I was able to get it to select from within the console, so I'm fairly(hopefully) certain it will work again.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the elements using the others alternatives:

- Finding HTML elements by tag name
- Finding HTML elements by CSS selectors

**Finding HTML elements by tag name:**

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
```

This example finds all `<a>` elements

**Finding HTML Elements by CSS Selectors**

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("a.website");
```

This example returns a list of all  elements with class="website".

**Note:** `querySelectorAll()` method does not work in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.

Comment: Alright, let me answer this with a little more clarity.  When I use 

    document.getElementsByTagName('a') 

I get the response [object Object] {length: 0}

when I use 

    document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]

I get undefined

Comment: Just post some example.